# Regex to find substring from a string

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have strings like:

```
str1 = eval(sum(feat(57),feat(57),feat(66))/feat(57));
str2 = eval(sum(feat(47),feat(55),feat(86)));
str3 = eval(feat(47)/sum(feat(51),feat(52),feat(53)));
str4 = eval(feat(63)/sum(feat(57):feat(66)));
```

I want to write a regex to get out as:

```
str1_output = (feat(57),feat(57),feat(66))
str2_output = (feat(47),feat(55),feat(86))
str3_output = (feat(51),feat(52),feat(53))
str4_output = (feat(57):feat(66))
```

I tried in the following way:

```
output = re.findall(re.compile(r"sum.*"),str_name)
```

This is giving correct output except str1.

Please suggest me a way to find out the desired output.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, @evuez. I tried in the following way:
re.findall(re.compile(r"sum.*"),str1)

This regex is giving correct output except 'str1'

Comment: Ok then add this to your question, you'll get more help :)

Comment: @evuez i added. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could try

```
sum\((?:\([^()]*\)|.)*?\)
```

It matches `sum` and the following **matching** pair of parentheses, and whatever are between them.

Example at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xM5oX6/1).

Regards.